# Passive voice with two objects

Tags: sentence-structure, passive

I have read a few grammar articles about german passive voice, but none of them mentions a special case in which there are two objects.

- **Active**: I gebe dir einen Stift.
- **Passive**:

  - Ein Stift wird dir von mir gegeben.
  - Du wirst von mir einen Stift gegeben.

I tried translating but I am not absolutely sure if I don't miss anything. Could you please confirm:

1. The passive voice construction above is correct.
2. The order of words is natural (although passive voice in german is less commonly used, compared to english).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example sentence is correct.

> <s>Du wirst von mir einen Stift gegeben.</s>

is wrong. "geben" doesn't work in passive in German as it does in English (The dative object - the receiver - in the active sentence needs to stay the dative object in the passive sentence.)

Or, in general, passive in German is built by using the accusative object of the active sentence as the subject of the sentence and the subject of the active sentence becomes the accusative object of the passive one. Dative objects are not affected by building a passive sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> Ein Stift wird dir von mir gegeben.

This is correct and perfectly fine.

> Du wirst von mir einen Stift gegeben.

This is wrong.

You could turn around the word order of the first variant to

> Dir wird von mir ein Stift gegeben.

Passives generally do two things:

- The patient of a transitive verb ("direct object") becomes the subject:

  > Die Frau malt ein Bild. -> Ein Bild wird gemalt.

  This is why the person of the passive verb is determined by the original object:

  > Die Frau malt dich. -> Du wirst gemalt.

  and the main error in your attempt.
- Other arguments of the verb, especially the original subject (the **agent**), become optional arguments ("freie Angaben"):

  > Die Frau malt ein Bild. -> Ein Bild wird [von der Frau] gemalt.
  >
  > Die Frau malt dich. -> Du wirst [von der Frau] gemalt.

  This is now not really differnt from other adverbials:

  > Ein Bild wird [im Garten] gemalt.

In our case, the verb has (in active) three obligatory arguments (giver, thing, and recipient), of which the thing is the patient.  So you might say

> Ein Stift wird gegeben.

although that's a bit weird. (I'd say for ditransitive verbs like *geben*, the second object ("indirect object") is almost required in passive, but I'm not entirely sure on this; in any cay you can use the above example as an ellipsis).  Then you can put in the other arguments:

> Ein Stift wird [von mir] gegeben.
>
> Ein Stift wird [dir] gegeben.
>
> [Von mir] wird ein Stift gegeben.
>
> [Dir] wird ein Stift gegeben.
>
> [Dir] wird [von mir] ein Stift gegeben.
>
> [Von mir] wird [dir] ein Stift gegeben.

The first position can also be filled by the pseudo-subject *es*:

> Es wird [dir] [von mir] ein Stift gegeben.